# How does Web Source operation's URL Pattern get it's argument when it's assigned a parameter?

Tags: oracle-apex

when you AutoREST-Enable a table through object browser> click table> REST tab, you will get a RESTful URI. If you then build a web source using that RESTful URI, you will get five operations - GET with a dot as URL pattern and GET, PUT, POST and DELETE operations with URL pattern has the value of :deptno. When you build a report with form on that web source you will find that all database operations work well, you can insert, update and delete through the form, and you can run the report to get all rows in the table. I need to know how the process work in the background? How the automatic row processing process knows which operation and handler to use? I know that Interactive Reports for example looks for the operation that have "Fetch Rows" it's database operation. So, I assumed that the Form's automatic row processing looks up for the Web source's operation with the database operation that relates to the process to be executed. For example, (correct me if I'm wrong) when clicking CREATE button, it denotes that an Insert process will happen, so, it will search for the web source's operation with the database operation "insert row", then it will find the handler that relates to the HTTP method attribute's value "POST". And the same goes for UPDATE and DELETE. I want to know if I am getting it right and I need to know how the URL Pattern gets it's argument for `:deptno`?

Answer (score 1):

your understanding of the form region picking the Web Source Operation is correct. Within the Form Region, the name of the clicked button (**:REQUES**T) actually determines the DML operation (**CREATE** = Insert, **SAVE** = Update, **DELETE** = delete).

A `:deptno` URL parameter must also be created within the **Parameters** section of the REST data source. Once that is in place, you'll see the form region node in the Page Designer Tree having a **Parameters** node - there you can map the Web Source Module parameter to a page item, an application item or something else.

Comment: That's another thing I do not understand. When you auto-REST a table like I said then build a web source module on it, you won't see parameters for URL patterns neither on the module nor on the operation level, although the help of URL pattern field says that you have to. Consequently, there is no parameters node under the Form node. Then how it gets it's value?

Comment: The URL pattern for an auto-REST table is the placeholder for the primary key column. Since a "Update Row" or "Delete Row" operation cannot work without a primary key, APEX takes the value for this parameter from the primary items of your form (or the primary key columns of your Interactive Grid). In this case, APEX "knows" where to get the value from, and so no explicit parameter definition is required.

Does that help?

Comment: Of course it helps, but in the following Oracle's video (unfortunately, it's in Arabic, but you can understand what the developer does as you see it), you could see in minute 22:13 that he build's Module, templates and handlers manually through RESTful services page. And in minute 27:20, he builds a web resource using the URI template he created manually. And in minute 58:04, you will see GET and PUT operations created with URL pattern :deptno without mentioning it as a parameter neither at the module or handler level. He created the DELETE operation afterward....

Comment: then created a form and report using that service and all operations work fine. How come?!

Comment: Any help @Carsten?

Comment: Sorry @Carsten , I forget to post the video's URL. Here it's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tybHZCJDkU&t=1727s

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the *primary key* values are special in a Web Source Module. In your case, the :deptno placeholder (as part of the URL) corresponds to the **DEPTNO** data profile column.
For the DML handlers (PUT, POST, DELETE) you don't need to define these as Web Source Module parameters, but the URL placeholders must match the column names in the data profile. This is by design - Web Source Modules are implemented to work this way.

Comment: as @Carsten said, **"The URL pattern for an auto-REST table is the placeholder for the primary key column."**. I am just saying it's working the same way when manually REST-enabling a table - the URL pattern does not need to be defined as a parameter neither in the module nor the operation level. And APEX will get it's value from the primary key items/columns. Am I right?